# Solr DataSource Request Parameters Not Being Recognized

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I'm trying to make the username/password for a Solr (7.5) data import handler to be dynamic, following the guidance [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#dih-request-parameters).

Here's my data config:

```
<dataConfig>
   <dataSource 
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://mysqlconnectionstring" 
    user="${dataimporter.request.jdbcuser}" 
    password="${dataimporter.request.jdbcpassword}"/> ...
```

And solrconfig:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

However, when I execute the dataimport command (e.g. http://mysolr.something/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&jdbcuser=foo&jdbcpassword=bar), I get (partial) responses like this:

```
"initArgs": [
"defaults",
[
  "config",
  "data-config.xml",
  "datasource",
  [
    "driver",
    "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url",
    "jdbc:mysql://mysqlconnectionstring",
    "user",
    "",
    "password",
    ""
  ]
]
```

]

If I look in the solr logs, I see entries like this:

> 18:56:32.076 [qtp1076770748-18] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter - Loading DIH Configuration: data-config.xml
>
> 18:56:32.087 [qtp1076770748-18] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter - Data Configuration loaded successfully
>
> 18:56:32.087 [qtp1076770748-18] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter - Getting configuration for Global Datasource...
>
> 18:56:32.087 [qtp1076770748-18] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter - Adding properties to datasource: {password=, driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, user=, url=jdbc:mysql://mysqlconnectionstring}

I just don't know what I am missing here, why won't it read the username/password from the request and populate the datasource from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with my kubernetes statefulset controlling the k8s cluster: it was holding on to old config somehow and this seems to work fine now that I explicitly deleted all pods in the statefulset.